Filter function in Base R
I was curious about methods to return duplicate values in a vector, list, or array in R. Focusing on a vector, I defined the following:
myvec <- c('a', letters)
which duplicates the letter 'a' in position 1 or 2 depending how you define it (position 2 in R). If I enter duplicated(myvec). I get a logical vector of F, T, F, F, ... as expected. However, when I enter:
Filter(duplicated, myvec)
The output is
character(0)
But I expect a. Why does Filter not return this value?

Filter calls the function duplicated for each element of vec. So, it calls duplicated(a), again duplicated(a), then duplicated(b) etc.
As duplicated is called for each element separately, it never sees both "a"s.

When you type Filter in the console, you will see the source code of Filter
> Filter
function (f, x) 
{
    f <- match.fun(f)
    ind <- as.logical(unlist(lapply(x, f)))
    x[which(ind)]
}

where element-wise filtering is committed. In that sense, you perform duplicated over each elements of myvec, and check them one by one.
Since a single value will never be identified as a duplicate of others, you always obtain False and nothing remains in the output, and that's the reason you got character(0).

If you want to obtain "a" as the expected output, you can try
> unique(myvec[duplicated(myvec)])
[1] "a"


As the other answers have already pointed out Filter acts separately on each component of the second argument.
If the second argument is a character vector, as in the question, then to use Filter apply it to table(myvec) rather than directly to myvec.
myvec |>
  table() |>
  Filter(f = \(x) x > 1) |>
  names()
## [1] "a"

Notes
Input used
myvec <- c("a", letters)

